# Remembrance from the First temple

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash

I read that the destruction of the first Beis Hamikdash was so thorough that there were no physical remains from the structure. This is not clear from the passukim in vayikra.
Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: I read this in Torah Nation by Reb Avigdor Miller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be such pesukim in Vaykira but the more commonly given source  is from Tehlim 137 which when discussing the destruction of the Beis Hamakdush says

עָרוּ עָרוּ עַד הַיְסוֹד בָּהּ

which indicates that it was razed down in destruction until it's foundations

Answer (score 0):

The question in itself was mistaken. I asked the question after I read this page but did not have it on hand. I misread the quote which I am attaching: [image]

This is talking about the Temple in מצרים, not the Beis Hamikdash. Thank you @schmerel for your answer.